# Set Maximum Zoom Scale for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have tried setting Maximum Zoom scale for UIWebview by

```
        webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=2.0;
        webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
```

But not able to do. If any body has any idea please tell..

Comment: what means by "not able to do"
1. the webView can't zoom?
2. the max scale can't limit the webview?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps :

1) Add static `const float zoomSc = 3.0`; Also add `UIScrollViewDelegate` in `.h` file

2) `yourWebView.scrollView.delegate = self`;

3) Add below scrollView delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale{

  if (scale > zoomSc)
  {
    scrollView.zoomScale= zoomSc;
  }
}
```

**EDIT** : Change `range` of `zoom factor`

Add these following in `UIWebViewDelegate's` method.

**Note** : Don't forget to set delegate for `UIWebView`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   //restrict zoomscale by adding javascript code
   //make changes to only maximum-scale value as i have set it to 10.0.
   NSString *strJSFunction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"function increaseMaxZoomFactor(){ var element = document.createElement('meta'); element.name = \"viewport\"; element.content = \"maximum-scale=10.0\"; var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; head.appendChild(element); }"];

  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:strJSFunction];
  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"increaseMaxZoomFactor()"];
}
```